# Excel Find and replace dialog shows default text

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins, addin-express

I have working on excel-addin. I have few UDF formulas in that, whenever i uses any of the formulas and press Ctrl+F to open find and replace dialog it shows UDF formula as default text in the search. Is there any way i can inspect how find and replace is picking the udf formula. I have checked the clipboard as well, nothing in there.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll find you put it there (whether or not inadvertently). Maybe try a different search and see what happens?